# How to properly pass an array as a function argument?

Tags: c, arrays, function, function-call, compound-literals

When I try to send an array in to the function I get an error.

This is my minunit test program:

```
#include "minunit.h"
#include "calc.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int tests_run = 0;

 static char * test_Repetitve() {
     mu_assert("error in test_Repetitive, Repetitive != 7", HistogramArray({1,2,3,4,5,6,7})== 7);
     return 0;
 }

 static char * all_tests() {
         mu_run_test(test_Repetitive);
     return 0;
 }

 int main(int argc, char **argv) {
     char *result = all_tests();
     if (result != 0) {
         printf("%s\n", result);
     }
     else {
         printf("ALL TESTS PASSED\n");
     }
     printf("Tests run: %d\n", tests_run);

     return result != 0;
 }
```

The line that I have problem with is

```
mu_assert("error in test_Repetitive, Repetitive != 7", HistogramArray({1,2,3,4,5,6,7})== 7);
```

and it goes in to this function :

```
    int HistogramArray(int one[])
{
    int arrchk[TWENTY+ONE] = { ZERO }, i, j,counter=0;//arrchk is an array that counts how many times the number appears.
    for (i = ZERO; i<N; i++)
        arrchk[one[i]]++;
    for (i = ZERO; i<TWENTY+ONE; i++)
    {
        if (arrchk[i] != ZERO) 
                        {
                         printf("the number is %d ", i);//printing the histogram.
                          counter++;
                        }
        for (j = ZERO; j<arrchk[i]; j++)
        {
            printf("*");

        }
        if (arrchk[i] != ZERO)printf("\n"); 
    }
return counter;
```

I basically need to check if the counter is 7 in the Histogram Function, any suggestions?

Comment: `{1,2,3,4,5,6,7}` is not an array, it's a brace enclosed initializer. By itself, it has no type.

Comment: I don't see any [images](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collage) ;-)

Comment: please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is with the syntax `HistogramArray({1,2,3,4,5,6,7})`, here `{1,2,3,4,5,6,7}` is not an array on it's own, it's a brace-enlosed list of initializers. The `HistogramArray()` function expects an array as argument.

You can however, use it with a syntax of **[compound literal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_syntax#Compound_literals)**

```
  HistogramArray((int []){1,2,3,4,5,6,7})
```

to use it like an array.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.5.2.5,

> A postfix expression that consists of a parenthesized type name followed by a braceenclosed
>   list of initializers is a compound literal. It provides an unnamed object whose value is given by the initializer list.

and

> If the type name specifies an array of unknown size, the size is determined by the
>   initializer list as specified in 6.7.9, and the type of the compound literal is that of the
>   completed array type. [...]

So, this provides with you with an unnamed array which is initialized with the elements in the brace enclosed list.

Comment: @AlexKreinis Strictly speaking, this is not *passing an array as a function argument*, this is *writing an array literal*. Arrays cannot be passed to functions. What gets passed dto the function in tbis case is a pointer, not an array. It will still work for you but ideally you should know the difference.